# Change tint color on email dialog opened through ActivityView

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, navigation, uiactivityviewcontroller

We have white tintColor in whole app.

See on cancel button. Is is white.

[image]

How can we change its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing [UIBarButtonItem appearance], e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]};

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
 [barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[barButtonItem];
```

Change title and color according to your requirement.

Comment: It doesn't change tint color in email dialog